# in c# how would I regenerate a contextMenu?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I have a dynamically generated context menu.
How do I reload all of the information in it every time it is clicked?

in the below the MyGlobals.ifparam array is altered frequently.

```
if (MyGlobals.ifparams[0, 0] != null)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem mnuItemNet1 = new ToolStripMenuItem(MyGlobals.ifparams[0, 0]);
    mnuContextMenu.Items.Add(mnuItemNet1);
    mnuItemNet1.ToolTipText=MyGlobals.ifparams[0, 1];

    ToolStripMenuItem mnuDHCP1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("DHCP");
    ToolStripMenuItem mnuStatic1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("Static");
    if (MyGlobals.ifparams[0, 8] == "1") { mnuDHCP1.Checked = true; mnuStatic1.Checked = false; }
    else { mnuDHCP1.Checked = false; mnuStatic1.Checked = true; }    
    mnuItemNet1.DropDown = mnuContextMenu1;

    ToolStripMenuItem mnuIP1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    mnuIP1.Text = MyGlobals.ifparams[0, 3] + "/" + getCIDR(MyGlobals.ifparams[0, 4]);

    mnuContextMenu1.Items.Add(mnuDHCP1);
    mnuContextMenu1.Items.Add(mnuStatic1);
    mnuContextMenu1.Items.Add(mnuIP1);
}
```

I'm mostly concerned with mnuContextMenu1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Opening` event on the context menu class. Here you can rebuild the context menu before it's shown.

**EDIT: Here is an example:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Subscribe to the opening event.
        // Example only: You should subscribe to the event in the designer.
        _contextMenu.Opening += new CancelEventHandler(OnContextMenuOpening);
    }

    private void OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {           
        // Create a menu item.
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        item.Click += new EventHandler(OnItemClick);

        // Clear the content menu and add the item to it.
        _contextMenu.Items.Clear();
        _contextMenu.Items.Add(item);
    }

    private void OnItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show the text of the item just for fun.
        MessageBox.Show(((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: would you be able to elaborate? Do I subscribe outside of the method that generates the menu? (inside Form1()?)

Comment: @csharpidiot: I updated my entry with an example of how to use the context menu opening event.

Comment: thanks! haven't gotten it to work exactly that way (can't subscribe to the event in the designer because it doesn't exist until run time.
However I did it manually and it (mostly) works. It doesn't update until the second time I click it...

However, I'm much closer.